# jquery - hold the changed text by onclick method on page reload is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on add to favourite functionality of my website,every thing is working fine.
When i click `add to favourites button` ajax call is inserting that data in db and changing the button text to 'remove from favourites'

Now problem is when i reload the page ,it again reset the text of button to 'add to favourites' which was previously marked as favourite.

My code is

```
<button  class='btn btn-sm btn-info favourite_feature'  value="<?php echo $id;?>">add to favourite</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".favourite_feature").click(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    var postid = _this.val();
    $.ajax({
        type     : 'POST',
        url      : 'add_to_favourite.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data     : {course_id : postid},
        success  : function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response.error_type == 'no error'){
                alert('done');
                (_this).html(_this.html()=='add to favourite' ? 'remove from favourites' : 'add to favourite');
            }else{
                if(response.error_type == 'login'){
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:ADDED SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'includes/dbconfig.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['google_data'])){
        $response = array('success' => 0, 'error_type' => 'login'); 
        echo json_encode($response);
    }else{
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $c_id = $_POST['course_id'];
        $_SESSION['course_id']=$c_id;
        $u_email = $_SESSION['google_data']['email'];
        $check_favourites = "SELECT * from favourites_table where user_id = '$id' and course_id = '$c_id'";
        $check_favourites_query = mysqli_query($conn,$check_favourites) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $check_favourites_result = mysqli_fetch_array($check_favourites_query);
        if($check_favourites_result){
            $del = "DELETE FROM favourites_table where user_id = '$id' and course_id = '$c_id'";
            $del_favourites = mysqli_query($conn,$del) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        }else{
            $insert_query = "INSERT INTO favourites_table(course_id,user_id,user_email) VALUES('$c_id','$id','$u_email')";
            mysqli_query($conn,$insert_query);
        }
        $response = array('success' => 1, 'error_type' => 'no error'); 
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is your database storing the favorite post data for each user or for each post (ie. any user can toggle its status)?

Comment: You should fetch the data from your DB and depending on the favourite state saved in DB `echo` corresponding button text (the same way as you `echo` button `value`)

Comment: i have edited the post by adding server side code,Yes its storing the favourite result id along with user id in db

Answer (score 2):

On the server-side you need to check whether the item is currently added to favourites or not before you render the button, and set the text appropriately.

I don't know your data structure but let's say in PHP you can define a boolean variable `$isFavourite`, based on the database field where this is stored against the item in question (presumably the same item defined by `$id` in the snippet you've given).

So all you'd have to do is change the markup to:

```
<button class='btn btn-sm btn-info favourite_feature' value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo ($isFavourite == true ? 'remove from favourites' : 'add to favourites')?></button>
```

Comment: i have edited the post by adding server side code,Yes its storing the favourite result id along with user id in db

Comment: ok so my answer will work. in the server-side code that runs when the page reloads then you just need to find out if there's a row in favourites for that course and user and then set $isFavourite true or false accordingly. Looks like you already know how to query the database so that should be easy.

Comment: server side code only runs when button get clicked and how could i pass the variable from server side code to front end ,i tried doing this by declaring 1 variable on server side code and then tried to echo on front-end,but its giving `undefined variable error`,i need little help

Comment: the server-side code you've posted is done when the button is clicked. But there must be some other php code which runs when the page is loaded. The bit that contains your `<button>` tag (shown in the original question). That's where you should place your query.

Comment: after successfull ajax call how can i declare `$isFavourite` variable,i'm not getting the logic

Comment: you don't do it after the ajax call. You do it in when the page is reloaded, as I described in my last comment. You said the problem is happening when the page is reloaded. This is nothing to do with the ajax call.